Collaborative Development Environment for ASP.NET Web API Backend and React Frontend
Hello StackOverflow community,
I am part of a team working on a web application project. Our backend is being developed with ASP.NET Web API and SQL Server, while our frontend team is using React. The backend and frontend will be on separate projects. The frontend will communicate with the backend through API endpoints.
We are looking for a method to collaborate on these two projects concurrently. Specifically, we need an environment where the developing API can be called by the frontend. The goal is to ensure that the two projects can communicate with each other and perform their functions during the development process.
Could anyone suggest a suitable setup or tools that would facilitate this kind of collaborative development? Any advice or best practices for this scenario would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance for your help!

You mentioned they are two separate projects. Are they part of the same solution?

@JuanR Yes, what I mean is they are 2 separate projects developed by 2 teams. The frontend UI would be developed with React on another platform not .NET (possibly Vite). And the frontend needs to call the API. Thanks.

Generally speaking, you will need an integration environment.
Development on both projects will be done independently and an integration strategy can be agreed upon.
Each side can use tools to mock the requests during development.
The ASP.NET Web API side can be tested locally by simulating requests through a tool such as Postman.
The React app can use a mock object to simulate calls to the backend. The mock can then return the expected responses.
With continuous integration, both projects can be independently checked in and thus automatically built and deployed to the integration environment where they actually interact with each other (integration).
If you are truly bent on having them both collaborate real time, you can point the React App in Development to the integration environment. After all, the backend is a dependency for the React App, but this would slow down development on the client side.
